# Implementing separate frameworks for different architectures in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, frameworks, arm64

I had a question about implementing separate frameworks for different architectures.
This is a third party framework, so I can't create it myself.
This is what i've got:

> .framework (arm64)
>   .framework (armv7, armv7s) 
>   .framework (i386) 
>   .framework (x86_64)

This is the same framework but build for different architectures.
I was wondering how I should implement this in a project so that I can build it for the app store as well. 
Currently I have a target for each architecture, but I can only build 1 target for production ..?

Can somebody help me with this? A step-by-step guide would be nice, because i've tried multiple things so far.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can use lipo.

```
lipo -create <path-to-.framework (arm64)> <path-to-.framework (armv7, armv7s)> -output <path-to-fatlib>
```

The above command will yield a fat library which includes the input symbol files together.

You can do this for all the libraries in order to test your app on both simulator and device. I recommend to not use the simulator symbols in your release to reduce the size of the app.

The arm64, armv7, and armv7s are the device architectures while i386 and x86_64 are the simulator ones. You don't need armv7s if you don't have. In case you have a symbols file for armv7 then don't care about armv7s.

The symbols file located inside the framework with the same name of the framework. So you will give path as `Some.framework/Some`.